# JToolTip alignment issues

Tags: java, swing

I have a JToolTip attached to the onclick event of a JTextField.

I want the JToolTip to popup aligned with the right edge of the JTextField instead of its left edge as it does by default.

Is there any way to set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `getTooltipLocation(...)` of the component your clicking on!

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    JTextField field = new JTextField() {
        @Override
        public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent event) {
            Rectangle position = frame.getBounds();
            return new Point(position.x, position.y);
        }
    };

    field.setToolTipText("test");
    frame.add(field);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```